# Flashing appropriate 200 message upon logout, laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Using laravel 5.2, I'm hitting a logout listener at the time of logging out that logs the user out of their cognito instance.

This seems to be successful but I"m having a hard time getting a working message to flash on logout, specifically, I want the 200 message response from the auth call below

I have handled the JSON for errors at the endpoint call, but if the part of my try block is successful then I get a 200 response with message "User logged out successfully".

How should I properly flash the 200 message on the sign in screen/redirect after logging out?

```
     try {

        $authService = new AuthService();
        $authLogout = $authService->logout($logoutToken);

    }catch (\Exception $e) {

        $response = json_decode($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
        $message = $response->message;

        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($message);

    }
```

Comment: I dont see the usage of https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#flash-data

Comment: $request->session()->flash('msg', $message);

Comment: @MsuArven I can't use the session though, because they will be logged out destroying the session

Comment: @Flame I just added that to my code, but my issue is that upon logout I'm flushing the session, so would that work? I just want to retain the 200 message from my endpoint and flash on the sign in screen after logout

Comment: Just flush the line before you do `session()->flash()`. The Flashed variable will only be shown once since it automatically deletes itself

Answer (score 0):

Add to a session

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

Retrieve from the session

```
$value = session('key');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use the rest api, you can wrtite this in your logout fonction

```
public function logout (Request $request) 
    {
        $token = $request->user()->token();
        $token->revoke();
        $response = 'You have been succesfully logged out!';
        return response(["message"=>$response], 200);
    }
```